# "flag provided but not defined" when trying to start google cloud sql proxy

Tags: command-line, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=my-instance=tcp:3306 -credential-file "cloud-sql-key.json"
```

Running this command produces the following error:

```
flag provided but not defined: -credential-file
```

Not sure why because I do provide the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag is `-credential_file` (underscore, not dash).

Comment: and how do we pass token?

Comment: The argument for -credential_file is the path to the service account token. So when you have the IAM service account set up, you can download the key, and then that key is what you pass to the argument.